# How do I pass a row of a CSV into a validation object - with one row every call of the object

Tags: python, csv, oop

So I have an Object that is validating a CSV file through a NamedTuple()...

```py
# !/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv
import typing as T
import logging
from csv import DictReader
from collections import OrderedDict


class Validate(T.NamedTuple):

    field1: str
    field2: str
    field3: str


    @classmethod
    def from_row(cls, row: dict):
        return cls(**{key: type_(row[key]) for key, type_ in cls._field_types.items()})

    @staticmethod
    def validate_csv(reader: DictReader) -> bool:
        for index, row in enumerate(reader):
            try:
                PCW.from_row(row)
            except Exception as ERROR_MESSAGE:
                logging.error(f'{ERROR_MESSAGE} -- row_number: {index + 1}')
                return False
        return True

def execute(csv_file):
    input_file = csv.DictReader(open(csv_file))
    return Validate.validate_csv(input_file)


execute("../test_csv.csv")
```

Excuse me if this is a design pattern, I'm fairly new to OOP programming.

This will work if we have a CSV file of the form:

`field1,field2,field3`

If all 3 fields are of the type  then it works - if any are of a different type then it will log. This is the intended behavior.

However, what I would like to do is have some sort of method that runs just one row at a time, and every call it runs the next row through validation.

- since atm the whole CSV is validated, all I want is to be able to run the same validation but on one row at a time.

ie:

```py
def csv_file(filepath: str):
    with open(filepath) as file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=',')
        for r in reader:
            yield r


for i in Validate.csv_file("../test_csv.csv"):
    Validate.validate_csv(i)
```

However, this doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 0):

One approach towards  "all I want is to be able to run the same validation but on one row at a time" is to create a static/class variable in which you keep the number of the row that was processed (by calling the class-method validate_csv), See bellow code snippet  :

```
import csv

class Test:

  #class variable
  _line = 0

  @classmethod
  def valid_csv(cls,filename):
      with open(filename) as csvfile:
          readCSV = list(csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=','))
          try:
             row_you_want = readCSV[cls._line]
             #implement validation
             print(row_you_want)
          except IndexError:
             print("Finished processing")

     #update class variable
     cls._line +=1
```

Bellow you can see that the _line attribute gets updated with the corresponding row each time when valid_csv it is called:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, I think this would fail for my `from_row` method though, I might have to rethink it...